# JS: implementing hash table and getting NaN

Tags: javascript

I am looking at code to implement my own hash table ( https://www.educative.io/blog/data-strucutres-hash-table-javascript) and I am confused about the `calculateHash` function.
Whenever I check add to the `ht` after creating an instance of the HashTable, the hash shows as `NaN`.

```
class HashTable {
  constructor() {
    this.values = {};
    this.length =  0;
    this.size =  0;
  }

  calculateHash(key) {
    return key.toString().length % this.size;
  }

  add(key, value) {
    const hash = this.calculateHash(key);
    If (!this.values.hasOwnProperty(hash)) {
      this.values[hash] = {};
    }
    if (!this.values[hash].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       this.length++;
    }
    this.values[hash][key] = value;
  }

  search(key) {
     const hash = this.calculateHash(key);
     if (this.values.hasOwnProperty(hash) && this.values[hash].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       return this.values[hash][key];
     } else {
       return null;
     }
  }
}

//create object of type hash table
const ht = new HashTable();
//add data to the hash table ht
ht.add("Canada", "300");
ht.add("Germany", "100");
ht.add("Italy", "50");
```

Comment: `this.size` is `0`. Anything modulo 0 is NaN.

Comment: size is supposed to be more than 0 from the start. This is supposed to be the bucket size, and it should be slightly larger than the actual number of items in the hashtable. In Java, I think they try to keep a ratio of 3:4 for number of items to bucket size

Comment: thanks @smac89 . Do you technically need a bucket for a hash table though?  Can you just base it off of key/value pairs without being in a bucket?

Comment: Looks like an error in the tutorial since `this.size` isn't being set anywhere.

Comment: The concept of buckets is due to the fact that there is no perfect hash function. Because of this some items will inadvertently hash to the same location thus forming a collection/bucket of items. The buckets are necessary unless you know beforehand what kinds of items will be stored in your hashtable and you have come up with a perfect hash function that evenly distributes these items into unique positions